# Blank application (C ++ / WinRT) does not appear when I want to create a new project?

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-10-desktop, winui

I have installed visual 2019 the newest sdk and C ++ (v14x) Universal Windows Platform tools and I don't see the option to create Blank App (C ++ / WinRT).

Anyone else has happened? How did you solve it?

I have attached an image.
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you installed the  C++/WinRT Visual Studio Extension:  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264 see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt#visual-studio-support-for-cwinrt-xaml-the-vsix-extension-and-the-nuget-package

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

I installed C++/WinRT Visual Studio Extension

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264

by Simon Mourier's Suggestion.

Thanks